# How to apply the Masoretic note, "2x, once plene and once defectively" to Ruth 1:1?

Tags: hebrew, tanach, grammar-dikduk, mesorah-tradition

In Ruth 1:1, there is a Masoretic note on שְׁפֹט which I do not understand:

[image]

The picture is a little unclear, but the note says (I have highlighted the letters with a dot above them):

> **ב** חד מ**ל** וחד ח**ס**

I read this as:

> Twice, once spelled *plene* and once spelled defectively

However, I don't understand how this applies to this word. The form (a qal infinitive construct of שׁפט) occurs more than twice (13 times, if my count is correct: Ex. 18:13; 1 Sam. 8:5, 6; 1 Kgs. 3:9 [2x]; Joel 4:12; Ob. 1:21; Ps. 10:18; 51:6; 96:13; 98:9; Ruth 1:1; 1 Chr. 16:33).

(If the form is interpreted as a qal infinitive *absolute* I can understand (this form occurs only once elsewhere and is spelled *plene* there: Gn. 19:9). But I really don't see how this form could be read as an infinitive absolute. Also I would expect a reference to Gn. 19:9 in that case.)

How should I interpret this note?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Masoretic note you have is from the [Leningrad Codex](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Leningrad-codex-18-22-megilloth.pdf/page1-1275px-Leningrad-codex-18-22-megilloth.pdf.jpg). However, the Aleppo Codex indicates in the *masorah gedolah* in Chronicles that there are 3 instances of the word (see also [Mikraot Gedolot haKeter](https://www.mgketer.org/mikra/31/1)):

[image: Aleppo Codex]

[image: Masorah gedolah]

These are:

- [Ruth 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth.1.1?lang=bi) (short):
  וַיְהִ֗י בִּימֵי֙ **שְׁפֹ֣ט** הַשֹּׁפְטִ֔ים וַיְהִ֥י רָעָ֖ב בָּאָ֑רֶץ וַיֵּ֨לֶךְ אִ֜ישׁ מִבֵּ֧ית לֶ֣חֶם יְהוּדָ֗ה לָגוּר֙ בִּשְׂדֵ֣י מוֹאָ֔ב ה֥וּא וְאִשְׁתּ֖וֹ וּשְׁנֵ֥י בָנָֽיו׃
- [Proverbs 31:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.31.9?lang=bi) (short)
  פְּתַח־פִּ֥יךָ **שְׁפָט**־צֶ֑דֶק וְ֝דִ֗ין עָנִ֥י וְאֶבְיֽוֹן׃
- [Chronicles II 20:9](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.20.9?lang=bi) (long):
  אִם־תָּב֨וֹא עָלֵ֜ינוּ רָעָ֗ה חֶרֶב֮ **שְׁפוֹט֮** וְדֶ֣בֶר וְרָעָב֒ נַֽעַמְדָ֞ה לִפְנֵ֨י הַבַּ֤יִת הַזֶּה֙ וּלְפָנֶ֔יךָ כִּ֥י שִׁמְךָ֖ בַּבַּ֣יִת הַזֶּ֑ה וְנִזְעַ֥ק אֵלֶ֛יךָ מִצָּרָתֵ֖נוּ וְתִשְׁמַ֥ע וְתוֹשִֽׁיעַ׃

See in Aleppo Codex respectively: [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Aleppo-HighRes3-Ketuvim3-Job-Proverbs-Ruth-Song.pdf/page47-1240px-Aleppo-HighRes3-Ketuvim3-Job-Proverbs-Ruth-Song.pdf.jpg) (top right column), [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Aleppo-HighRes3-Ketuvim3-Job-Proverbs-Ruth-Song.pdf/page46-1240px-Aleppo-HighRes3-Ketuvim3-Job-Proverbs-Ruth-Song.pdf.jpg) (right column) and [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Aleppo-HighRes3-Ketuvim1-Chronicles.pdf/page55-1240px-Aleppo-HighRes3-Ketuvim1-Chronicles.pdf.jpg) (centre of page, first word).

See in Leningrad Codex respectively: [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Leningrad-codex-18-22-megilloth.pdf/page1-1275px-Leningrad-codex-18-22-megilloth.pdf.jpg) (first row of bottom right column), [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/34/Leningrad-codex-17-proverbs.pdf/page23-1275px-Leningrad-codex-17-proverbs.pdf.jpg) (last row of top left block) and [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Leningrad-codex-14-chronicles.pdf/page55-1275px-Leningrad-codex-14-chronicles.pdf.jpg) (left column, row 11)

These masoretic notes are usually based on identical pronunciation (here *shefot)* rather than grammatical considerations. The example in [Bereishit 19:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.9?lang=bi) is pronounced *shafot,* so it couldn't be listed here. That means the Leningrad Codex either didn't consider the case in Proverbs a *kamatz katan* or it might be that the masoretic note there is mistaken.

Comment: Just speculating here: is it possible that the author of the masorah in the Leningrad Codex distinguished between pronunciation of holam and kamatz katan (as is common in ashkenazi pronunciation today)?

Comment: @JoelK I've been thinking about it a lot, but once I saw a Babylonian manuscript that had the equivalent of _cholam_ at a _kamatz katan._ So, despite the different tradition, I have doubts about such distinction. And it's also not promising that the MGhK omitted this note.

Comment: In Tiberian Hebrew, which is reflected in these manuscripts, cholem and kamats katan were pronounced differently. A kamatz katan was pronounced literally as a short kamatz, hence they shared a graphic sign. A kamatz katan was used however in some situations where a cholem became unstressed, e.g. כל with a makkef or שְׁפָט־צֶ֑דֶק above. However, all three instances of שפט included in the answer above are "construct infinitives" of שפט and in that sense are the same word.

Comment: @Argon What is the evidence for your first claim? (I'm really curious!) I could only use an external Babylonian source ([MS Heb. d. 49](https://genizah.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/fragments/full/MS_HEB_d_49_6a.jpg)): See the word ויקם with a : sign (which corresponds to the Tiberian _cholam)_ in the place of a (current) _kamatz katan._

Comment: @Kazibácsi https://www.openbookpublishers.com/10.11647/obp.0163.02.pdf

Comment: @Argon would you not read the case in Proverbs as an imperative?

Comment: @user24663 The instance in Proverbs is an imperative, in Ruth it's possessive and in Chronicles it's a noun in my view. Only the pronunciation matters. (This is why Strong's 8196 and 8199 are not distinguished.)

Comment: Right, I was referring to @Argon's statement that all three cases are construct infinitives. In the tradition that I was taught in, the imperative is a distinct morph, and you wouldn't call an imperative a construct infinitive even though the pronunciation overlaps.

Comment: @user24663 Sorry, did not look close enough. Only Ruth has an infinitive, it would seem. Anyways: check out pgs. 262ff, 268ff. It would certainly have been odd for Masoretes to invent a system where hatef patah is a short patah, hatef segol is a short segol, hatef hirik is a short hirik and hatef qamats is a short holem!

Comment: @Argon Once I asked Prof. Ofer, and he told me that the _sheva na_ and the _chataf patach_ were the same in Tiberian, which would contradict your (otherwise perfectly logical) claim.

Comment: Additionally: [Hadayat al-Qari](https://www.openbookpublishers.com/10.11647/obp.0194.02.pdf) pages 158, 174, 176, 190. There is significant confusion about this matter because indeed in some Sefardic pronunciations (and in Israeli Hebrew) that hataf kamets = holem. But it is not universal in all Hebrew traditions. Indeed, it is not the the case in the Yemeni pronunciation, where hatef kamets has the quality of a kamets.

Comment: @Argon In Babylonian it's sure that cholam and kamatz katan were the same (see my example and p. 251 in Khan's book). And the Yemenites took the Babylonian tradition, so I'd be surprised by that fact. (Yet, I'm not an expert of their tradition.)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.academia.edu/37462039/Geoffrey_Khan_Vocalization_Babylonian_in_Geoffrey_Khan_et_al_eds_Encyclopedia_of_Hebrew_Language_and_Linguistics_vol_3_Leiden_Brill_2013_953_963), p. 957, bottom right paragraph. (You might enjoy the rest too!)

Comment: Should not the phrase, "That means the Leningrad Codex either didn't consider the case in Proverbs..." be corrected to say, "That means the **Aleppo** Codex either didn't consider the case in Proverbs..." ?

Comment: @Joseph The masoretic note in Aleppo assumes that it was pronounced in the same way (i.e. kamatz katan is the same as cholam).

Answer (score 6):

My understanding here is that the *masorah* here is relating to the word שְׁפֹט / שְׁפוֹט without any prefixes.

That word does appear only twice in Tanach: here (spelled *defective*) and *plene* in [II Chronicles 20:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.20.9?lang=bi)

> אִם־תָּב֨וֹא עָלֵ֜ינוּ רָעָ֗ה חֶרֶב֮ שְׁפוֹט֮ וְדֶ֣בֶר וְרָעָב֒ נַֽעַמְדָ֞ה לִפְנֵ֨י הַבַּ֤יִת הַזֶּה֙ וּלְפָנֶ֔יךָ כִּ֥י שִׁמְךָ֖ בַּבַּ֣יִת הַזֶּ֑ה וְנִזְעַ֥ק אֵלֶ֛יךָ מִצָּרָתֵ֖נוּ וְתִשְׁמַ֥ע וְתוֹשִֽׁיעַ׃

where, interestingly, it would seem to be a straightforward noun (equivalent to the word מִשְׁפָּט).

(There also seem to be [other versions of the *masorah*](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/31/1/1) which quote a third instance: the word שְׁפָט appearing in [Proverbs 31:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Proverbs.31.9?lang=bi).)

Comment: Thanks! My source for the other cases of the infinitive treats the case in 2 Chr. 20:9 as a separate lemma, so it didn't show up in my list. Is there any way I could have found it, other than using a modern concordance? It seems slightly odd that the Masoretes would remark that there exists a second instance, but not where to find it.

Comment: @user24663 Again, this is based on pronunciation rather than grammar, and it is listed in the _masorah gedolah_ of the Aleppo Codex. I couldn't figure out, whether that note was also in the Leningrad Codex.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Yes, I have read your answer, it was very helpful as I did not expect it to be based on pronounciation. But apart from the case in Proverbs (which indeed has **ל** for me), how would I have found the reference to 2 Chr. 20:9 from Ruth 1:1?

Comment: @user Haha! That is the trick! In the codex the note is usually placed only at one of the instances. Therefore, I really recommend using the Mikraot Gedolot haKeter, which lists them all.

Comment: @Kazibácsi that's... yeah, that's great! In my Bible, the BHS, the reference is given in neither direction (but that's not much less helpful than a reference in one direction). Other bidirectional references are given at both places (e.g. וְתִשְׁמַע in Dt. 32:1 and 2 Chr. 20:9), but I know now that I cannot rely on that. Thanks for the MGhK resource, that will be very helpful!